# Downloading xml from url in Azure

Tags: c#, xml

I'm downloading xml from:    https://ims.data.gov.il/sites/default/files/xml/imslasthour.xml
from Desktop application
 The function for download is

```
private static XDocument LoadDoc(string url)
{
    Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url));

    XDocument doc = null;

    var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

    request.Proxy = null;

    request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    var cc = new CookieContainer();

    request.CookieContainer = cc;

    using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var content = sr.ReadToEnd();

            try
            {
                doc = XDocument.Parse(content);
            }
            catch (XmlException e)
            {
                Log.Error(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    return doc;
}
```

In all machines application  works properly.
     When it was run on Azure virtual machine, instead of xml file it returned:

```
<head>
<script>
Challenge=243009;
ChallengeId=196151745;
GenericErrorMessageCookies="Cookies must be enabled in order to view this page.";
</script>
<script>
function test(var1)
{
    var var_str=""+Challenge;
    var var_arr=var_str.split("");
    var LastDig=var_arr.reverse()[0];
    var minDig=var_arr.sort()[0];
    var subvar1 = (2 * (var_arr[2]))+(var_arr[1]*1);
    var subvar2 = (2 * var_arr[2])+var_arr[1];
    var my_pow=Math.pow(((var_arr[0]*1)+2),var_arr[1]);
    var x=(var1*3+subvar1)*1;
    var y=Math.cos(Math.PI*subvar2);
    var answer=x*y;
    answer-=my_pow*1;
    answer+=(minDig*1)-(LastDig*1);
    answer=answer+subvar2;
    return answer;
}
</script>
<script>
client = null;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    var client=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        client = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
    };
}
if (!((!!client)&&(!!Math.pow)&&(!!Math.cos)&&(!![].sort)&&(!![].reverse)))
{
    document.write("Not all needed JavaScript methods are supported.<BR>");

}
else
{
    client.onreadystatechange  = function()
    {
        if(client.readyState  == 4)
        {
            var MyCookie=client.getResponseHeader("X-AA-Cookie-Value");
            if ((MyCookie == null) || (MyCookie==""))
            {
                document.write(client.responseText);
                return;
            }

            var cookieName = MyCookie.split('=')[0];
            if (document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName)==-1)
            {
                document.write(GenericErrorMessageCookies);
                return;
            }
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    };
    y=test(Challenge);
    client.open("POST",window.location,true);
    client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge-ID', ChallengeId);
    client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge-Result',y);
    client.setRequestHeader('X-AA-Challenge',Challenge);
    client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type' , 'text/plain');
    client.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>JavaScript must be enabled in order to view this page.</noscript>
</body>
</HTML>
```

response.StatusDescription id "OK"

Browser in Azure returns proper xml. If community can help me to cope with this problem?

Comment: it is because the page needs to use javascript. see the last answer at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982365/how-to-enable-javascript-when-making-an-httpwebrequest

Comment: It works properly on my home pc. It does not work from cloud